# how to disable the resizing button in a tkinter gui app?

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I want to build a tkinter app and I need to disable this button...[image: Here is the button]

how do I do that???

Comment: read the [docs](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/toplevel.html) (hint: look for `.resizable`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example disables the resizing of a tkinter GUI using the `resizable` method.

```
import tkinter as tk
    
class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
        tk.Canvas(self,width=100,height=100).grid()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).grid()
    root.resizable(width=False,height=False)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though you have an answer, here's a shortened code, without classes (if you want):

```
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable(False, False)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is a typo: `geometry`. Also it's better to use `.resizable(False, False)` as `.resizable` takes in booleans.

Comment: @TheLizzard Typo corrected and booleans used instead of ```0```s. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this. It should help.

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(tk, width='you can decide', height='you can decide')
canvas.pack()

canvas.mainloop()
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The question specifically asks how to disable the full-screen button.

Comment: Avoid importing everything from a module. Also, it doesn't solve the OP's problem. They want to disable the maximize button.